# Angular2/4 with bootstrap scss (Angular webpack starter)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack, angular-webpack-starter

I am trying to setup a simple project with Angular2/4 with bootstrap.

I cloned the [Angular-Webpack-Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter) repo, removed the things which are no longer needed and added bootstrap according to the link https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-4-and-Sass-(and-jQuery)

When I start the server through `npm run server`, it is getting compiled correctly. But css/scss are not getting loaded.

As you see in the below snapshot, css are not getting loaded.
[image]

I am using the following HTML in the HomeComponent

```
<div>
    <h1>HOME</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"> 1 of 2 </div>
            <div class="col-md-6"> 1 of 2 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"> 1 of 3 </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> 1 of 3 </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> 1 of 3 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the bootstrap css files, then those should be included in your index.html file like so

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

You could also reference the bootstrap package installed in the `node_modules` folder after running `npm install` from the root directory of the project

However, if it is a component's css that is not getting loaded, then try setting encapsulation to None like so. When you load a component's css, it is not applied globally but making `ViewEncapsulation.None` will make them global.

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Does this answer your question? Also I would recommend using the AngularCLI tool and then running `ng serve`

Comment: if we refer the css directly from CDN what is the point of dependencies mentioned in packages.json?

Comment: You could do either, they both work. I'm not exactly sure what the advantages of one over the other are though

Comment: It will work I Agree , what happen when application become offline?

Comment: If you don't have internet, then the CDN won't work which is something to consider if you develop on the go. Then you would have to install bootstrap instead of referencing the CDN

Comment: In his question he is already mentioned , he is installed the bootstrap dependencies , So there is no relevance of referring the dependencies from CDN

Comment: @AlexNelson: I am loading bootstrap from bootstrap loader through config (in my case weback.common.js). I am also using ViewEncapsulation.None. I have followed https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-4-and-Sass-(and-jQuery) to the letter. But I am still missing something.

Comment: Try viewing the page source in your browser to double check if the css files were actually loaded

Answer (score 0):

Once you downloaded the seed application , you have to install all the node packages mentioned in **package.json**. To install navigate in to the root directory and run the command

```
npm install
```

If bootstrap is not installed , install the dependencies and refer the dependencies directly from the node_modules downloaded in your directory

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose of using bootstrap-loader